# How to read MailItem or RDOMail into MimeKit?

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption, mimekit

Does anyone know how to read the Microsoft Outlook's MailItem or Redemption's RDOMail into a MemoryStream so that MimeKit's ParseMessage could take it?

I am trying to read a p7s signature from the email and I'm not sure how to to do it. I've already gone through many places and documentations.

Can someone give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDOMail.Attachments will contains the p7m attachment. You can just save it as a file using RDOAttachment.SaveAsFile.

Comment: Ah ok, it was my bad, so the attachment came in with just MimeTag multipart/signed but it has no filename what-so-ever. Thank you for your help Dmitry in the past few days hehe...